# Program help! After user hits enter the program ends

Tags: c, char, ascii

Ok I am making a program that reads two characters from the user and then prints the ASCII letters between those two characters.
The problem is that when the program runs it prompts the user to enter the first character and once the user hits enter the program ends. 
What am I missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){


      char firstchar;
      char secondchar;
      int variable;
      int highest;
      int lowest;
      char ASCIvariable;

      printf("Please enter a character. ");
      scanf("%d", &firstchar);

      printf("Please enter another character. ");
      scanf("%d", &secondchar);

      if(firstchar < secondchar) 
      {
         secondchar = highest;
         firstchar = lowest;
      }else{
         firstchar = highest;
         secondchar = lowest;
      }

      variable = lowest;

      for ( variable != highest; variable < highest; variable++ )
      {
          variable = ASCIvariable;
          printf(ASCIvariable);
      }

      return 0;
}
```

I clearly also don't understand how to post code on this site. I need four spaces manually entered before EVERY line of code?

---

Update here is the current code also control k will not allow paste....

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


    char firstchar;
  char secondchar;
   int variable;
  int highest;
  int lowest;
  char ASCIvariable;

  printf("Please enter a character. ");
  scanf(" %c", &firstchar);

  printf("Please enter another character. ");
  scanf(" %c", &secondchar);

  if(firstchar < secondchar) 
  {
 highest = secondchar;
 lowest = firstchar;
}
  else
  {
  highest = firstchar;
  lowest = secondchar;
}

  variable = lowest;


 for (variable != highest; variable <= highest; variable++ )
  {
        ASCIvariable = variable;
      printf("%c ", ASCIvariable);

  }


    return 0;
}
```

It successfully allows the user to enter both characters and then prints the letters between the two. I think that is correct?

Comment: Try to insert your code and press Ctrl+K ;-)

Comment: And to format code, you can either add 4 spaces manually or select the whole code and press the **{}** button or hit CTRL+K.

Comment: Ok that would be easier :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```
printf("Please enter another character. ");
scanf(" %c", &secondchar);  /* Note the extra space and %d is changed to %c*/
```

Also change your for loop to:

```
for ( ; variable <= highest; variable++ ) /* Should be <= */ {
   ASCIvariable = variable; /* Reverse */
   printf("%c", ASCIvariable); /* %c */
}
```

Your assignations are also incorrect:

```
if(firstchar < secondchar) 
{
 highest = secondchar;
 lowest = firstchar;
}
else
{
  highest = firstchar;
  lowest = secondchar;
}
```

`a = b;` means copy contents of `b` into `a`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have changed my code to this. It will accept the first character then prompt the user for a second and then crash saying it has stopped working.

Comment: Should it just be printf("%c ", ASCIvariable); ?

Comment: Ok I changed it to that now the program runs. It asks the user for the first character, prompts for the second but before the user can enter a character it prints the ASCII values.

Comment: @Noob ,Did you do everything that this comment says? `/* Note the extra space and %d is changed to %c*/`. To solve your issue, just add a space before `%c` in the second `scanf`.

Comment: @CoolGuy `printf("%c", printf(ASCIvariable));` came from irresponsible copy-paste. Thanks.

Comment: Yes everything is as suggested. I don't understand the blank semicolon in the loop though. And the program prompts and allows the user to enter both characters but does not execute the loop or print the ascII

Comment: @NoobNeuromancer The initialization part of the for loop is mandatory it can be left as shown in the code `for(; <cond> ;)` is valid

Comment: @Noob , Just move `variable = lowest;` before the semicolon and you'll get it.

Comment: @Noob , What are your inputs? Also change `%c` to `%d` in the `printf` in the loop.

Comment: for ( variable = lowest; variable <= highest; variable++ )
  {
    ASCIvariable = variable;
   printf("%c ", ASCIvariable);
   
  }
  Nothing prints

Comment: I'm not reading any input in during the loop. I am just trying to print the characters betweeen the lowest and highest character.

Comment: @Noob , I'm asking what characters do you input for the first two `scanf`s?

Comment: printf("Please enter a character. ");
  scanf(" %c", &firstchar);
  
  printf("Please enter another character. ");
  scanf(" %c", &secondchar);

Comment: @Noob, What do you type in when you run the program when the program prompts you to?

Comment: Yes I can enter in the first and second character and then the program ends

Comment: Super dont like the commenting on this site. It can't act like a fourum? How does one post an update besides these comments?

Comment: @Noob , I'm asking **What do you enter?** and who is super?

Comment: @Noob ,StackOverflow is not a forum. It is a Q and A site. Use the comments for clarifing things. If you have a question to ask, you can ask it. You can also edit your question with an EDIT part if you want to post the new and partially working code.

Comment: Ok it had someones suggested edit which lead me to believe i could not edit it myself.

Comment: @Noob , Just change `%c` to `%d` in the `printf` in the loop and it will work just fine!

Comment: @NoobNeuromancer I just copied your code and pasted [here](http://ideone.com/0Ytujd) and it gives correct output for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using wrong format specifier might lead to UB. You need to scan a character

```
scanf("%c", &firstchar);
```

Then flush the newline char using

```
scanf(" %c",&secondchar);
```

The space before the `%c` consumes the newline char.

Comment: @NoobNeuromancer Did it fix your issue? If you want to jusr pint char use `putchar(ASCIvariable)` or `printf("%c\n",ASCIvariable);`

Answer (score 1):

1)You must get input with format specifier `%c` for characters

2)You must consume the `newline` after entering first character

3) You seem to be confused with assignment statements

`a=b`
assigns the valure of `b` to `a` and not the other way around.

```
printf("Please enter a character. ");
scanf(" %c", &firstchar);
//The space before %c will consume the newline

printf("Please enter another character. ");
scanf(" %c", &secondchar);

if(firstchar < secondchar) 
{
    highest=secondchar ;
    lowest=firstchar ;
}
else
{
    highest=firstchar;
    lowest= secondchar ;
}

//Changed the for loop to get characters between two inputs
variable = lowest+1;
for ( ; variable < highest; variable++ )
{
     ASCIvariable= variable ;
     printf("%c ", ASCIvariable);

}
```